# Как прикрутить к боту продавцу корзину покупок

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Есть представления как решить вопрос, но реализовать его в код не получается, прошу помощи

```
elif a.data == 'pr1.1':
    kbd1 = InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    bt1 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Добавить в корзину', callback_data='basket')
    bt2 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='Удалить из корзины', callback_data='delete_basket')
    bt3 = InlineKeyboardButton(text='<--Назад', callback_data='back')
    kbd1.add(bt1, bt2, bt3)
    photo1 = open('photo/prod1_1.jpg', 'rb')
    media1 = InputMediaPhoto(photo1, MESSAGES['product1_1'])
    await bot.edit_message_media(chat_id=a.message.chat.id, message_id=a.message.message_id, media=media1,
                                 reply_markup=kbd1)
elif a.data == 'back':
    return await edit_section(a.message)
```

Comment: Ну и какие у Вас представления, чтобы решить вопрос?

Comment: Создать и сохранять информацию в БД, и находясь в корзине черпать оттуда информацию